# How to get the arity of "super"?

Tags: ruby

Say you are overwriting a method in a subclass with a different arity:

```
class A
  def foo(arg)          # arity is 1
    # doing something here
  end
end

class B < A
  def foo(arg1, arg2)   # arity is 2
    super(arg1)         # <- HERE
  end
end
```

Is there a way to get the arity of `super` on line HERE?

(The real use case: I'm calling `super` knowing that the superclass doesn't take any arguments. However, if the superclass implementation (in a gem) ever changes, I'd like to issue a warning.)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not sure if there's a simpler way.. `self.class.superclass.instance_method(__method__).arity` `__method__` is from 1.9 you can be explicit with a symbol const too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding your real use case: there's no need to check the arguments yourself. Just call

```
super(arg1)
```

and Ruby will raise an `ArgumentError` if the argument count doesn't match.

#### Update

Due to some downvotes, I think I should answer your initial question.

> How to get the arity of “super”?

Starting with Ruby 2.2, there's [`Method#super_method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Method.html#method-i-super_method) and [`UnboundMethod#super_method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/UnboundMethod.html#method-i-super_method):

```
class A
  def foo(arg)
  end
end

class B < A
  def foo(arg1, arg2)
  end
end

B.instance_method(:foo).arity #=> 2
B.instance_method(:foo).super_method.arity #=> 1
```

From within `B#foo`, you could write:

```
class B < A
  def foo(arg1, arg2)
    method(__method__).super_method.arity #=> 1
  end
end
```

Comment: +1, makes more sense to me. I think he would also like to rescue from *ArgumentError* and throw a warning there.

Comment: Answering the question by saying that the answer is unncessary, are we?

Comment: @BorisStitnicky you don't have to reinvent the wheel if the desired functionality is already built-in, do you?

Comment: Well, it is certainly imaginable to write a method that determines arity of super() using trial and error. But svoops question is deeper than that. It touches the issue of super() being somwhat 'indirect' method call. It raises more issues than just arity. For example, how do I locate super()? How do I know from which ancestor module is it taken? How do I obtain unbound method from it? A hacky answer cover these issues up. I was looking forward to someone giving a real answer, using #arity method.